# Error while using overview mode using gnome in arch

Tags: linux, gnome

I am not getting the proper output of the Gnome overview mode while pressing the super key. Here's the screenshot of my overview mode. Not all the currently opened windows are shown and the one active is only shown.
[image: overview error gnome arch]

Comment: Do you have [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) installed? It may cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is always related to some installed extensions, that are broken in the latest version of Gnome Shell (especially 3.36). Try to disable all extensions, reload Gnome with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, enter. Confirm that overview now works as expected, and start enabling extensions one by one and checking overview. If you find the extension, that causes this, leave it disabled and wait till extension developers fix this problem.

I still have this problem with [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/).