# Ubuntu application sidebar on openSUSE

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, opensuse

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome on my main computer, which has this sidebar on the left side where I see currently running applications or pinned applications (no idea what that's called, the launcher?).

On my secondary computer I have to use openSUSE for different reasons, and I'm also using Gnome there. On the openSUSE machine, there is no such permanent sidebar. I can only see a similar menu (though not over the whole height of the screen, the top and bottom is empty) when I click the "Activities" button in the top left corner of the screen.

I'd really like to have an Ubuntu-style dock/launcher/whatever on my openSUSE machine, but I can't figure out a way to do that. Is that a Gnome setting I can just change? Is there an additional package that I need to install to do that? Can I even do that without removing openSUSE and installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension called [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) which will bring you a dock on the screen as you are used to from the Ubuntu. Many distributions provide this extension as default. It is highly customizable. You can change a position, size, theme, background, autohiding and so on...

If you don't have experience with Gnome extensions, I would recommend you to read first 3 paragraphs of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579226/220439) or you can search for something simmilar on the internet yourself.